# Missing data in Stata

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stata, missing-data, garch

I have a GARCH time-series dataset of 5217 observations, spanning roughly 20 years. One of the variables, the trade-weighted US dollar index, misses 108 values, and as far as I can tell completely random. What would be the best way to handle these missing datapoints?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @whuber I would like to add multiple variables, including the for mentioned dollar index, to the conditional variance of some commodities.

Comment: Depends on the available data for US dollar index. If there are many non-missing values before and after the 108 missing data points and the US dollar index is not volatile, the best course of action is interpolation. Little would be gained from stochastic missing data imputation.

Comment: @stans thank you for responding. If more variables have this (relatively few missing data points, random, independent of other variables) would this be a problem?

Comment: Depends on the data. Typically... if the missing slots are sparse and few, interpolation works (for time series analysis). In fact, the data they give you on Quandl, Yahoo and Datastream have implicit interpolations already.

Comment: @stans never knew this about Datastream! I think I'll just go with interpolation in that case. Thank you for your help.